# Ajax call to SubversionEdge server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, svn, version-control, subversion-edge

I want to make **Ajax** call to **SubversionEdge** server on click of a button designed on **aspx** page and copy files from my local machine to the server. I am looking for documentation but so far has not found one that could help me achieve this. Does anyone know a work-around for this?